# Add a stack to stack array - System.NullReferenceException Error

Tags: c#, list, stack, nullreferenceexception

My code:

```
Stack<int>[] stk = new Stack<int>[5];
stk[2].Push(54);
stk[1].Push(768);
```

Error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

The debugger shows that I have 5 stacks initialized to null values.  How can I initialize those 5 stacks so I can push values into them?

I also tried:

```
List<Stack<int>> data = new List<Stack<int>>( );
```

then created stacks a, b, c, etc and pushed them into data with `data.Add(a)` etc.
and this works fine ( `data[1].Push(345)` ) but the number stacks I need to store varies and I want to be able to iterate through the stacks or reference them individually.

Or is there a better, hopefully easier, way to do this with arrays maybe?

Comment: `Stack<int>[] stk = new Stack<int>[5];` does not create 5 stacks. It an array of 5 pointers to a stack. You actually need to create each stack too. `stk[0] = new Stack<int>` etc

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Works perfectly.  As a newbie I read all the information suggested by Jeroen however could not readily see how it applied to what I was doing.  Re-reading all of that, your answer helped me see how it did.  Thanks.